# Change printer orientation in terminal

Tags: command-line, printing

When I go to system-confing-printer I am able to change printer orientation.

[image]

How can I do it over terminal?

Comment: Look at [this page](https://www.cups.org/doc/options.html). But is it useful, since you, sometimes, have to change it by programs you use to print?

Comment: Thanks, I've also found out that I can change that settings in
 /etc/cups/printers.conf file

Comment: Congratulations! You can transcript your solution to an answer right below. Type it with details, so it will useful to other users. I will rate it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be easily changed in this file

```
/etc/cups/printers.conf
```

here you will find all your installed printers. They are separated like this:

```
<DefaultPrinter Lexmark-XM1100>
.
.
.
</DefaultPrinter>
```

according to [CUPS Documentation](https://www.cups.org/doc/options.html#ORIENTATION:%7E:text=Setting%20the%20Orientation), you can modify this file by adding or modifying one of the rotating options. For example, I have added this line to rotate for 180 degrees

```
Option orientation-requested 6
```

after I restarted cups:

```
sudo systemctl restart cups.service
```

and called

```
system-config-printer
```

orientation was already changed to "Reverse portrait"

And if we want to change orientation on the command line, following [page](http://www.it.uu.se/datordrift/maskinpark/skrivare/cups/)
gives us info how to do it.
The

```
lpadmin -p <printer-name> -o orientation-requested-default=N
```

option rotates the page depending on the value of N:

(to get the printer names, run `lpstat -p | awk '{print $2}'`)

[image]